# A structure that cannot be imported into a structure body

Tags: go

**initialize/config.go**

```golang
package initialize

type DatabaseConfig struct {
    MysqlConfig MysqlConfig `yaml:"mysql"`
    RedisConfig RedisConfig `yaml:"redis"`
}

type MysqlConfig struct {
    Host            string `yaml:"host"`
}

type RedisConfig struct {
    Host     string `yaml:"host"`
    Port     int    `yaml:"port"`
    Password string `yaml:"password"`
    Database string `yaml:"database"`
}
```

**initialize/cache.go**

```golang
package initialize

import (
    "main/global"

    "github.com/chenyahui/gin-cache/persist"
    "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"
)

func InitCache(r *DatabaseConfig.RedisConfig) {

    // redisStore := persist.NewRedisStore(redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    //  Network: "tcp",
    //  Addr:    "127.0.0.1:6379",
    // }))
    // global.Cache = redisStore
}
```

The `InitCache` method in the `cache.go` file accepts parameter Redis configuration, but this position is reported error. The error message is as follows: `DatabaseConfig.RedisConfig undefined (type DatabaseConfig has no method RedisConfig)compilerMissingFieldOrMethod`

Comment: You should use RedisConfig  instead

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `DatabaseConfig` instead

```golang
func InitCache(c *DatabaseConfig) {
    c.RedisConfig
}
```

Or

Directly pass the field

```golang
func InitCache(c *RedisConfig) {
    //
}

// and in somewhere
var cfg DatabaseConfig
InitCache(&cfg.RedisConfig)
```